# what is the complexity of this matrix sum code?

Tags: c#, complexity-theory

i have just started to learn about complexity,
and i have found this piece of code,
what is the complexity of this code? is it O(n!)?

```
public static int func(int[][] mat)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < mat.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            sum += mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not `O(n!)`. You could easily find out what's the complexity by trying to think what is happening for each value of `i`:

- For i = 0 the internal loop will be executed once.
- For i = 1 the internal loop will be executed twice.
- For i = 2 the internal loop will be executed thrice.
- ...
- For i = k the intenal loop will be executed k+1 times.

So in total we will have to calculate the following sum

```
1+2+3+...+ n+1 = (n+1)(n+2)/2 = (n^2+3n+2)/2
```

The above sum is clearly `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of complexity, Time and Memory Complexity. I think here you are wondering about the Time Complexity.

In your example, I assume that the size of your array is NxN. In order to calculate Time Complexity, you can count the steps. So, if we start first `for` loop from 1 to n:

```
i = 0, with the second loop 1 addition.
i = 1, with the second loop 2 additions.
...
i = n, with the second loop n + 1 additions.
```

Total number of steps is 1 + 2 + ... + n + (n+1) = (n+1)*(n+2) / 2

That is why this example's Time Complexity is **O(n^2)**.

Comment: Replace n with i.

Comment: For `i = n`, the additions are `n+1`. (+1) because you stated explicitly the two types of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

No, the answer is not O(n!).

The simplest way is set a value for "i" variable, with this work you can understand the complexity.

I'll tell you how you can find the complexity of your code:

the declaration complexity is 1. if I want to show an example of your code I can point to :

```
int sum = 0;
```

and for loop:
   [(see image) Complexity description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uufsw.jpg)

T(n) = (n+1) + n*(n+2) + n*(n+1)
T(n) = 2n^2 + 4n + 1

==> O(n ^ 2).

I hope my description has been helpful.